# Showing multiple products in classic asp. Using database

Tags: asp-classic

I have an access table like this: with 100 products

```
Product Id, 
Product Name, 
Image Path, 
Price
```

I can easily display these products on my web page using asp code.

I want to add a button under each product which will allow the user to add the product to a shopping cart.

My page shows 30 items at a time. This is the HTML for my page. When I click on any button, I call java sctipt function mentioned below to submit the form.

```
<table class="retail">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="images/<%=rs.fields("image")%>" width="125" height="125"/>
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold;color: #151B8D;text-align: center;font-size: 10px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                <%=rs.fields("details")%>
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold;color: red;text-align: center;font-size: 14px; padding: 0px 1px 1px 1px;">
                <%=rs.fields("productid")%>
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold;color: red;text-align: center;font-size: 16px; padding: 0px 1px 1px 1px;">
                USD $<%=rs.fields("price")%>.00
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" id="details" name="details"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="productid" name="productid"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="button" value="Add to Trolly" id="cmdAdd" name="cmdAdd" onClick="javascript:callMe(this,'<%=rs.fields("details")%>','<%=rs.fields("productid")%>','<%=rs.fields("price")%>')"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>




<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function callMe(obj,details,prod_id,price) {
    var prodnm = document.getElementById("productid");
    prodnm.value = prod_id;

    var itemprice = document.getElementById("price");
    itemprice.value = price;

    var trollyform = document.getElementById("trollyform");

    document.forms["trollyform"].submit();
}
```

THis is the code i write to check form submition values:

```
<%

Response.Write "<br>Product Code value : " & request.Form("productid")
Response.Write "<br>Price value : " & request.Form("price")
```

%>

And as s response I am getting this:

My page shows 30 items and it gives me this if I click any add to cart button. So the button i click, it gives me value for that but it also gives me comma separated values for rest

Product Code value : RNG-2, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
Price value : 10, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

Basically first value is the value of the button i click for the product for rest of the products on that page it gives me COMMAs

Comment: You use the Product Id. It is definitely the primary key and will uniquely identify each and every product, right?

Comment: If the `Product id` isn't the primary key then create one typically a random id or you could use an autocrement value which would require you to create a new field in the table.

Comment: Just a side note: Have you considered to put a checkbox next to each article and one "global" Add-to-cart button?

Comment: the problem is your populating the form input "productid" with multiple values.  Is the code you posted the full page code?  if not post all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in one page, if that's your concern. The code [posted by cavillac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683032/447356) is good start, instead of pointing to different page just point to the same page but still have the query string values to indicate what product to add:

```
<a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?mode=add&itemID=<%=rs("Product Id")%>">Add to Cart</a>
```

Now in your page, have such code block:

```
If Request.QueryString("mode")="add" Then
    productID = Request.QueryString("itemID")

    If IsNumeric(productID) Then
        arrCurrentCart = Session("UserCart")
        If IsArray(arrCurrentCart) Then
            ReDim Preserve arrCurrentCart(UBound(arrCurrentCart) + 1)
        Else
            ReDim arrCurrentCart(0)
        End If
        arrCurrentCart(UBound(arrCurrentCart)) = productID
        Session("UserCart") = arrCurrentCart

        Response.Write("item added to cart")
        Response.END
    End If
End If
```

This is very basic example, using plain array as Session variable to store the items added - hope the intention is clear.

Comment: thanks all, please have a look code in my original message.. and please reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="cart.asp?mode=add&itemID=<%=rs("Product Id")%>">Add to Cart</a>
```

Something like that where rs is your recordset that you're looping through and "cart.asp" is a page designed to manage your cart.

Comment: I have only one ASP where i am doing everything. Reason is, I would like to show cart items on the left.
So its all ONE PAGE navigation stuff.

I do this briefly:
- Create DB connection
- Read Table based on the Link Clicked by the user

So I have conditions in page like this to go into block of code for that selection: I am listing my code for a selection

MY page shows 30 items at the moment.

Comment: @user1122575 first, don't shout. You can post code using the code formatting icon in the editor. Second, you can do it all in one page I'll post my own answer shortly.